# Why is my identifier collision rate increasing?

Tags: hash, collision, identifier, hash-collision, user-tracking

I'm using a hash of IP + User Agent as a unique identifier for every user that visits a website. This is a simple scheme with a pretty clear pitfall: **identifier collisions**. Multiple individuals browse the internet with the same IP + user agent combination. Unique users identified by the same hash will be recognized as a single user. I want to know how frequently this identifier error will be made.

To calculate the frequency, I've created a two-step funnel that should theoretically convert at zero percent: `publish.click` > `signup.complete`. (Users have to signup before they publish.) Running this funnel for 1 day gives me a conversion rate of **0.37%**. That figure is, I figured, my unique identifier collision probability for that funnel. Looking at the raw data (a table about 10,000 rows long), I confirmed this hypothesis. 37 signups were completed by new users identified by the same hash as old users who completed `publish.click` during the funnel period (1 day). (I know this because hashes matched up across the funnel, while UIDs, which are assigned at signup, did not.)

I thought I had it all figured out...

But then I ran the funnel for 1 week, and the conversion rate increased to **0.78%**. For 5 months, the conversion rate jumped to **1.71%**.

What could be at play here? **Why is my conversion (collision) rate increasing with widening experiment period?**

I think it may have something to do with the fact that unique users typically only fire `signup.complete` once, while they may fire `publish.click` multiple times over the course of a period. I'm struggling however to put this hypothesis into words.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1% is still low. it implies a load factor of < 5%. How big is your table? How many entries are present?

Comment: @wildplasser Added some clarification to your points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible explanations starting with the simplest:

1. The collision rate is relatively stable, but your initial measurement isn't significant because of the low volume of positives that you got. 37 isn't very many.  In this case, you've got two decent data points.
2. The collision rate isn't very stable and changes over time as usage changes (at work, at home, using mobile, etc.). The fact that you got three data points that show an upward trend is just a coincidence. This wouldn't surprise me, as funnel conversion rates change significantly over time, especially on a weekly basis. Also bots that we haven't caught.
3. If you really get multiple publishes, and sign-ups are absolutely a one-time thing, then your collision rate would increase as users who only signed up and didn't publish eventually publish. That won't increase their funnel conversion, but it will provide an extra publish for somebody else to convert on. **Essentially, every additional publish raises the probability that I, as a new user, am going to get confused with a previous publish event.**

> Note from OP. Hypothesis 3 turned out to be the correct hypothesis.